# Laravel View::share

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, global-variables, laravel-blade

Trying to work out a way to use global variables without actually creating a global variable.

I am working on a framework that I will use for all future projects and wish to have a database table containing the websites changing features (site name, colours, logo link etc)

If I wasn't using Laravel I would just include a functions file into my header include which set up an array of all these values so I could just call it.

```
<?= $constants['business_name] ?>
```

In Laravel, I could make a function to take a name and then return the value but seems excessive waste of db calls.

I found:

```
View::share
```

But I am getting variable undefined errors.

Tried this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $constants = DB::table('constants')->get();
    return $constants;
    View::share('constants', $constants);
}
```

In my BaseController but the error is shown, any idea?

Comment: Check out View Composers in laravel. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Answer (score 2):

You return from the constructor before even calling `View::share()`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $constants = DB::table('constants')->get();
    return $constants;  // <<<<<<
    View::share('constants', $constants);
}
```

Actually a constructor should never return something, so removing that line will do:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $constants = DB::table('constants')->get();
    View::share('constants', $constants);
}
```

---

You might also want to look into view composers to make data globally available without the need for a constructor:

[View composers - Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers)